# Why blocks are not displayed on the page?

Tags: django, django-templates

I ran into such a problem, the blocks do not want to be displayed on the page, which I do not really understand, since I did not work with the template engine before.
this is code views.py

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'Homepage/index.html'
model = Goods
context_object_name = 'goods'

def sale(request):
    return render(request, 'Homepage/sale.html')
```

This is code of index.html

```
 <td>{% block sale %} {% endblock %}</td>
```

This is code of sale.html

```html
{% extends "index.html" %}

{% block sale %}

<td class ="sale">
      <img src="image">

        <h1 class="description">description</h1>

  <a class="buy" href="#openModal" >
    <span >Купить</span></a>
  <h1 class="price">цена</h1>
  </td>


{% endblock %}
```

And this is the construction of the template
[image]

This is code of urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

app_name = 'Homepage'
urlpatterns = [    
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(),       name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
    path('', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),

]
```

Comment: There is no URL calling the sale view.

Comment: @yagus Clearly, but how to write?

Answer (score 0):

```py
def sale(request):
    return render(request, 'sale.html')
```

since `sale.html` file is outside of the folder Homepage, you should remove the Homepage prefix from the template name.
You should also make sure the URL you're trying to reach calls the sale view.

Comment: No, it does not work, but you can see, the question I updated there I added the code from urls.py

Comment: There should be an indentation issue or URL definition error. Move the sale URL to the top of your `urls.py` and try to retrieve content from your browser by hitting the exact URL you use on urls.py file. If this doesn't solve your problem, try to unindent the function. Python cares about the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need an URL that calls the sale view.

```
urlpatterns = [    
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(),       name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
    path('', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('sale', views.sale, name='sale'),
]
```

Comment: So I moved the sale function from the IndexView class and added your code to urls.py, but it still doesn't work. I'm wondering if I don't need to add a link pointing to the template in index.html?